# How to pass state (select value) to the parent in React (hooks)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a `select` tag in my `Dropdown` component, and when the `select`'s value changes, the state changes to the selected option: (`StyledDropdown` is a select styled-component)

```
const Dropdown = () => {

const [chosenCity, setChosenCity] = useState("london")

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setChosenCity(e.target.value)
}

return (
    <StyledDropdown name="cities" id="cities" onChange={handleChange} value={chosenCity}>
        <option id="def" value="london" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>London</option>
        <option id="2" value="paris" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Paris</option>
        <option id="3" value="tlv" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Tel Aviv</option>
        <option id="4" value="ny" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>New York</option>
        <option id="5" value="tokyo" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Tokyo</option>
    </StyledDropdown>
)
}

export default Dropdown
```

and I also have a parent compoent (`App.js`) that needs to get the value of `chosenCity`.

How can I share the state between them (**child to parent**).

Comment: You could pass city and setCity from Parent to Child, use city as the value and remove the local state of chosenCity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I also have a parent component (App.js) that needs to get the value of
>   `chosenCity`.

This means that your state should be in `App.js` and your select should be controlled (receiving the value and change callback through props):

```
const App = () => {
    const [city, setCity] = useState("london");

    return (
        <Dropdown value={city} onChange={event = setCity(event.target.value)} />
    );
};


const Dropdown = ({value, onChange}) => (
    <StyledDropdown name="cities" id="cities" onChange={onChange} value={value}>
        <option id="def" value="london" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>London</option>
        <option id="2" value="paris" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Paris</option>
        <option id="3" value="tlv" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Tel Aviv</option>
        <option id="4" value="ny" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>New York</option>
        <option id="5" value="tokyo" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Tokyo</option>
    </StyledDropdown>
)
```

Comment: this is the cleaner solution, the interface/props of the `Dropdown` component is what you see used in many components, i.e. `value` and `onChange`, rather than specifically named props like `city` and `setCity`.  When interfaces get messy, it's easy to lose scope of that the component's function is

Answer (score 0):

Passing state in react should only be happening between parent to child.

In your case you could move `const [chosenCity, setChosenCity] = useState("london")` to App.js and then pass updater function to Dropdown:

```
const Dropdown = ({chosenCity, setChosenCity }) => {

const handleChange = (e) => {
    setChosenCity(e.target.value)
}

return (
    <StyledDropdown name="cities" id="cities" onChange={handleChange} value={chosenCity}>
        <option id="def" value="london" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>London</option>
        <option id="2" value="paris" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Paris</option>
        <option id="3" value="tlv" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Tel Aviv</option>
        <option id="4" value="ny" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>New York</option>
        <option id="5" value="tokyo" style={{appearance: "none", background: "rgba(0, 0, 0, .7)"}}>Tokyo</option>
    </StyledDropdown>
)
}

export default Dropdown
```

Comment: no, your prop and state function have the same name, this won't work the way you have written it